# I got this error: in if (nj > mxd) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed when use ea_spline function to fit soil profiles (250)data (0, 5, 15, 30

Tags: r, mapping, soil

```
   id UDepth LDepth    pred_SOC  pred_clay  pred_silt  pred_sand
1   E0104      0     34  1.99826638 32.8049544  53.997127  14.465008
2   E0104     34     65  0.48402158 34.1738029  49.573291  16.062620
3   E0104     65     90  0.66509650 32.1084719  49.219769  19.097817
4   E0104     90    122  0.59752099 35.2387287  51.333509  14.481591
5   E0104    122    150  1.28216980 37.8453248  50.050850  12.849485
6   E0111      0     44  2.25824940 15.1074782  48.252303  35.385856
7   E0111     44     75  1.33754807 20.0404496  44.590324  34.097422
8   E0111     75    150  0.95796527 32.3029005  47.524989  19.148218
9   E0113      0     45  0.39886937  1.1841857  12.158147  90.097350
 reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 2066 rows ]
```

Comment: Please provide the code that is reproducing this error. You have given us too little information to do anything about this.

Comment: ea_spline(obj, var.name, lam = 0.1, d = c(0,5,15,30,60,100,200), vlow = 0, vhigh = 1000, show.progress=TRUE)
then :
splineFit <- ea_spline(soilprofile_all, var.name = "pred_SOC", d = t(c(0,5,15,30)), lam = 0.1, vlow = 0, show.progress = TRUE). I used depths until 30 cm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I trying to calculate and rearrange the profile depths of the above database using ea spline function. but I got the mentioned error, so how can I solve this problem